# Cocoa custom cell in NSTableView: NSCell subclassing leak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nscell

I made a subclass of NSCell and overrided the setObjectValue function to achieve my need.Things are fine except there is a leak problem. The setObjectValue function of NSCell seems wont release its original object.

The object I give the class is a customize object which conform to the NSCopying Protocol and implemented the copyWithZone function as below

```
- (void)setObjectValue:(id < NSCopying >)object {

    // I tried to use [[self objectValue] release]; here but the app crashed 

    [super setObjectValue:object];

    //---- other iniatizlize here ---   
}
```

.

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    MapComponent *newCopy = [[MapComponent allocWithZone:zone] initWithType:self.componentType];
    newCopy.myImage = self.myImage;
    return newCopy;
}
```

I have found the same problem [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/173875-nscell-copying-and-objectvalue.html). There is no answer but may better discribe my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    MapComponent *newCopy = [[[MapComponent allocWithZone:zone] initWithType:self.componentType] autorelease];
    newCopy.myImage = self.myImage;
    return newCopy;
}
```

Comment: You should not return an `autorelease` value from a copy method!

Comment: Another problem here is that you are using the accessor `newCopy.myImage`, which initially has the same **pointer value** has `self.myImage`. What you want to do is direct pointer access: `newCopy->myImage = nil; newCopy.myImage = self.myImage;` Otherwise, `newCopy` will `release` self's `myImage` when it tries to make a copy of it.